# Why does relay switch cause change of voltage?

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay

I am making an Arduino Thermostat. The arduino draws power from an adapter and the relay draws power from the 5v arduino. I have an LED that changes color according to temperature brackets.

The heater, which i want to turn ON and off is also plugged in the same power strip.

The problem is: when the relay swtiches, there is a noticeable change in brightness on the LCD and LED light. Somewhere the voltage changes, but i can't figure out why and how to avoid it.

If I power the Arduino with a 9v battery instead of an adapter, things are fine, and there is no change in display or LED.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

"""(if it matters at all, i am using Pololu (https://www.pololu.com/product/3101) instead of Arduino Uno"""

In case schematic is not viewable, here is a bigger image:
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/7j8duh/screenshot/1024x768/

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgUyJA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note to anyone trying to read the schematic: it's created with CircuitLab. You can read it if you click "simulate this circuit".

Comment: Identify and link the relay component.

Comment: @transistor I put the exact model on the schematic, this is the link, just 10A instead of 7A as seen: http://www.microbot.it/en/product/75/Relay-Module.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relay module spec](http://www.microbot.it/en/product/75/Relay-Module.html) says:

> Supply voltage    +5V
>
> Supply current     72mA typ. (75mA max.)
>
> Current on pin IN  14mA typ.

That looks to me as though it will need 72 + 14 = 86 mA for the relay board.

The [Pololu spec](https://www.pololu.com/product/3101) says:

> The board can either be powered directly from the USB 5 V supply or
>   from a separate 5.5 V to 15 V source on the VIN pin, which is reduced
>   to 5 V by a **100 mA low-dropout (LDO) regulator**; you can access this 5
>   V supply through the 5V power output pin. Additionally, the ATmega32U4
>   contains an internal 3.3 V regulator whose output is available on the
>   3V3 pin. Current drawn from the 3V3 output should not exceed about 50
>   mA, and **when the board is being powered through VIN, the sum of the 5V
>   output current, 3V3 output current, GPIO output current, and current
>   used by the board itself (typically about 25 mA) should not exceed 100
>   mA**.

So just adding the board brings the total up to 86 mA + 25 mA = 111 mA.

I think the voltage regulator is under stress. You'll have to come up with another 5 V supply for the relay.

Comment: You are right, I was overloading the circuit. I switched to a different power adapter which has a flat 5V and also i had connected previously the vin (9v) to the 5v circuit, which now are separated and I have no such problem anymore. Thank you!

Comment: Well done. Just a note for future projects: the 5 V relays will required more _current_ than their 12 V equivalents for a given size / power. It makes sense to go for the higher voltage to keep them off the 5 V regulator. Also, relays don't need regulated voltage anyway, so they can work off the unregulated supply - even a transformer rectifier without smoothing capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the power load of the heater is causing a drop of the 5 volt adapter, given that the 9V battery is fine.  You might try a better regulated 5V adapter.  Have you measured the 5 Volts when the heater is on and off, does it change?  Does the 5 volts drop when the heater is plugged in to a different line circuit?

Comment: The adapter is roughly 9V adapter, not 5V, and its voltage does not change upon relay switch, i measured it.